# Crypto dont defined in twit module for angular-cli

Tags: api, twitter, cryptography, angular-cli

I have some problem with twit npm module and crypto, when i will make a get call for example

> this.T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-07-11', count: 100
>   }, function(err, data, response) {
>             console.log(data)
>           })

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: crypto.createHmac is not a function

When debug the error I can see the crypto isn't asigned
[crypto dont defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXtY2.png)

Here is my module:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

const Twit = require('twit');

const conf = {
  consumer_key:         'xxx',
  consumer_secret:      'xxx',
  access_token:         'xxx',
  access_token_secret:  'xxx'/*,
  timeout_ms:           60*1000  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.*/
};
@Component({
  selector: 'app-twitter',
  templateUrl: './twitter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./twitter.component.css']
})
export class TwitterComponent implements OnInit {
  private T;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.T = new Twit(conf);
  }

  makecall() {
    this.T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-07-11', count: 100 }, function(err, data, response) {
      console.log(data)
    })

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Finally I fix the problem creating a node server and serve the Twit through them

Comment: Ah okay so if I'm doing this in Electron, I'd want to put this in the main process I'm guessing...